# What is the concept on Start:Stop:Step

Tags: python

I am new to python and I seem to be unable to understand the concept in Start:Stop:Step. For example

word = "Champ"
print (word[0:5:2])

why do I get cap as I result ? if someone could help me with this I would truly appreciated

I tried using different numbers to see what the outcome was but even there I was not able to understand why was I getting that outcome

Answer (score 1):

Let's see this way:

```
word = "Champ"

print (word[0:5:2])
# you are taking index=0, then index=0+2, then index=0+2+2
# then index=0+2+2+2 (don't have this)
# so you got 0,2, and 4
# Hope, makes sense

print(word[0])
print(word[2])
print(word[4])
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's best to imagine it as a simple `while`-loop that creates an output. Take this example:

```py
string = "Champ"
start = 0
stop = 5
step = 2

index = start
output = ""
while index < stop and index < len(string):
    output += string[index]
    index += step

print(output)
# >>> Cap
```

Here the current `index` starts at the `start` parameter, and then adds the current item to the `output`, then increments by the value `step`. If ever the current `index` is larger than the length of the original string, or larger than the `stop` value, the `while`-loop exits. Hope this helps!